# What is an empty template argument <> while creating an object?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Here is some valid syntax:

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<> randomizer(0, 100);
```

How does it work, does it automatically deduce the object template? Why is it necessary to write `<>` at the end of the type? Can I not remove the `<>` and it will be the same?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Typically this can be used and works when the first and succeeding, or only, parameter has a default template argument (type or value if it is an integral). An additional case is when there is a template argument pack and it is empty.

The `<>` is still needed to identify it as a template type.

In this [case the type is declared as](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution);

```
template <class RealType = double>
class uniform_real_distribution;
```

Hence the default `RealType` for the template class `uniform_real_distribution` is `double`. It amounts to `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>`.

---

With reference to the [C++ WD n4527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf), §14.3/4 (Template arguments)

> When template argument packs or default *template-arguments* are used, a *template-argument* list can be empty. In that case the empty `<>` brackets shall still be used as the *template-argument-list*. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T = char> class String;
> String<>* p; // OK: String<char>
> String* q;   // syntax error
>
> template<class ... Elements> class Tuple;
> Tuple<>* t; // OK: Elements is empty
> Tuple* u;   // syntax error
> ```
>
> *- end example* ]

Comment: So this `std::uniform_real_distribution randomizer(0, 100);` is not a valid syntax, right?

Comment: @Narek. Correct, the `<>` is required.

Answer (score 9):

The class has the following declaration

```
template<class RealType = double>
class uniform_real_distribution;
```

As you can see it has default template argument of type `double`

So this declaration

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<> randomizer(0, 100);
```

is equivalent to

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> randomizer(0, 100);
```