# What is this template syntax and unsigned type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I'm new to C++ and I am have difficulty understanding this code:

```
template <typename T = unsigned>
```

1. What is `T = unsigned` means?
2. Does the compiler enforce the `unsigned` on the given type?

Comment: `3. List item` – what? BTW, `unsigned` is a synonym for `unsigned int` in this context (and many others).

Comment: It's a default template parameter type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a default template parameter; it is similar to a default function parameter. If you don't put in an argument, it will default to `unsigned [int]`. So imagine this:

```
template <typename T = unsigned>
struct foo
{
    T one;
    T two;
};
```

If I declare for example a `foo<char>`, the resulting structure will have two `char` members. But the default parameter lets me declare a `foo<>`, and *that* structure will have two `unsigned int` members, because `unsigned int` is the default.

Answer (score 1):

The template has a default parameter for the type `T`, in this case `unsigned int`.

The `unsigned` is short hand for `unsigned int`.

For example; in client code if the template was a class template, then an object could be declared with or without explicitly adding a type to the declaration;

```
ABC<> abc1; // the <> is required
ABC<unsigned int> abc2; // equivalent type to abc1
ABC<float> abc3;
```

[Related question, regarding the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31404809/3747990).